# Modifying html files in terms of tags?

Tags: python, html

I have several html files, whose contents are like this:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>A test</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;"> 
                    Stuff here <a>with a link</a>
                    <p>Or paragraph tags</p>
                    <div>Or a DIV</div>
                </td>
                <td>Another TD element, without the MenuTD id</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="\d\d\d\d_files/zannotationtargettoggle.css" type="text/css">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

where   `\d` is a placeholder of a digit, and the exact digit varies from file to file.

I want to write a Python program to convert each html file to the following form:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <title>A test</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="\d\d\d\d_files/zannotationtargettoggle.css" type="text/css">
        <td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;"> 
            Stuff here <a>with a link</a>
            <p>Or paragraph tags</p>
            <div>Or a DIV</div>
        </td>
    </body>
</html>
```

Specifically,

1. How can we extract the header tag `<header>...</header>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="\d\d\d\d_files/zannotationtargettoggle.css" type="text/css">` , given that they don't have IDs?
2. If the body tag has attributes e.g. `<body style="margin-left: 6px; cursor: default;" onload="InitBody();">...</body>`, How shall we first empty the content `...` inside its beginning and ending tags, and then add  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="\d\d\d\d_files/zannotationtargettoggle.css" type="text/css">` and the content of `menu_td` inside?

Thanks!

Comment: Use some html parsers like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Which HTML parsing library are you using? Everything you're asking for is doable, but each library has a different way of doing it.

Comment: Also, your HTML isn't valid. The only things you can have at top-level of an `html` are 0 or 1 `head`s and 1 `body`; `header` is a tag that goes inside bodies (usually wrapping an `h1` or similar). (Plus, it's HTML5-only, and you don't have a `doctype` declaration, which means your file is HTML3.)

Comment: @abarnert: any library that works. It has a `doctype`, and I simplified too much. In the html file, `header` is in front of `body`, not inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to modify the input document:

```
import bs4

doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s) # s your input html
td = doc.find('td')
doc.find('table').replace_with(doc.find('link'))
doc.find('div').replace_with(td)
```

Testing the resulting document:

```
>>> print str(doc)
<html>
<body><header>
<title>A test</title>
</header>
<link href="\d\d\d\d_files/zannotationtargettoggle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<td id="MenuTD" style="vertical-align: top;"> 
                    Stuff here <a>with a link</a>
<p>Or paragraph tags</p>
<div>Or a DIV</div>
</td>
</body></html>
```

or you could construct a new document:

```
doc = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)
doc2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html />')
doc2.html.append(doc.header)
doc2.html.append(doc2.new_tag('body'))
doc2.body.append(doc.link)
doc2.body.append(doc.find('td'))
```

Comment: Thanks. The part to be removed is complex, and not just `table` and `div` (I simplified the case).  Is there some way to remove the part, given what part is retained?

Comment: @Tim: Go read the BeautifulSoup introduction docs, which JuniorCompressor linked for you. Until you understand it, you won't understand any code he gives you. And once you do, you'll probably be able to write the code yourself. (Or, if not, you'll have a more specific question to ask than just "write my code for me".)

Comment: @Tim as abarnert says it's better to read the docs. BeautifulSoup is a very useful tool and I couldn't provide a specific solution under so general conditions.